# Shipping logs to my local windows ELK/Logstash file from remote centos7 using filebeats

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

I have ELK all this three components configured on my local windows machine up and running.
I have a logfile on a remote centos7 machine available which I want to ship from there to my local windows with the help of Filebeat. How I can achieve that?
I have installed filebeat on centos with the help of rpm.

in configuration file I have made following changes
**commented output.elasticsearch
and uncommented output.logstash (which Ip of my windows machine shall I give overe here? How to get that ip)**

AND
**filebeat.inputs:

- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:

  - path to my log file**

Answer (score 0):

### The flow of the data is:

`Agent` => `logstash` > `elasticsearch`

Agent could be `beat` family, and you are using `filebeat` that is okay.

You have to configure all these stuff.
on filebeat you have to configure `filebeat.yml`
on logstash you have to configure `logstash.conf`
on elasticsearch you have to configure `elasticsearch.yml`

I personally will start with `logstash.conf`

```
input 
{
    beats 
    {
     port =>5044
    }
}
 
filter 
{
#I assume you just want the log to run into elasticsearch
}
output 
{
         elasticsearch
        {
            hosts => "(YOUR_ELASTICSEARCH_IP):9200"
            index=>"insertindexname"
    }
         stdout
        {
                codec => rubydebug
        }


}
```

this is a very minimal working configuration. this means, `Logstash` will listen for input from `filebeat` in port `5044`. `Filter` is needed when you want parse the data. `Output` is where you want to store the data. We are using `elasticsearch output plugin` since you want to store it to `elasticsearch`. `stdout` is super helpful for debugging your configuration file. add this you will regret nothing. **This will print all the messages that sent to elasticsearch**

### filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /directory/of/your/file/file.log

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["YOUR_LOGSTASH_IP:5044"]
```

this is a very minimal working `filebeat.yml`. `paths` is where you want logstash to harvest the file.

When you done configuring the file, start `elasticsearch` then `logstash` then `filebeat`.

Let me know any difficulties